# Adding a Script tag in a DIV element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a **code** like this:

```
var myscript = document.createElement('script');
myscript.setAttribute('src','codescript.js');
document.head.appendChild(myscript);
```

The **result** is:

```
<head>
  <script src="codescript.js"></script>
</head>
```

Well, how do I change the code.I'm hoping to put the script into a DIV tag which will be more specific.

For example:

```
<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="this">
    <script src="codescript.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you want the content of script into the div?

Comment: Just put the script code in a div tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myscript = document.createElement('script');
myscript.setAttribute('src','codescript.js');

var div = document.getElementById('this');
div.appendChild(myscript);
```

**document.getElementById**: Get the element with the specified id which is passed to that function as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can simply use `$.getScript('codescript.js');` to load code.

See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/